# Обработка исключения недостатка памяти

Tags: исключения, qt, c++

Есть код:

```
void AddNoiseHandler::startHandler()
{
    try {
        emit setStatus(2);
        emit setPercent(0);

        // Может быть исключение, в c# можно словить OutOfMemoryException
        result = new QImage(*source);

        // Handle
        // ...

        emit setPercent(100);
        emit setStatus(5);
    } catch (QException* error) {
        emit setStatus(3);
        emit sendError(error);
    } catch (...) {
        emit setStatus(3);
        emit sendError(new QException());
    }
}
```

Когда слишком много изображений открыто, программа занимает больше 1000 мб оперативы. И соответственно, в этой строке может вылететь программа:

```
result = new QImage(*source);
```

Можно ли как-то избежать вылета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Не факт что вылетает из за перерасхода оперативы, попробуй проверь source на null (если не гаратнированно значение null при незарезервированности памяти для source попробуй использовать безопасные кьютишные указатели). Соответственно если нуль кидай ексепшн. Можешь создать свой класс, производный от QException/*obsolete*/*

---

Ну могу поздравить! В твоем конкретном случае (не универсально) решение есть. конструктор QImage возвращает null если нехватка памяти (

> "QImage constructors will create a
> null image if not enough memory exists
> instead of throwing an exception"

, но ты можешь кинуть исключение сам). А в общем случае динамическое выделение памяти само по себе не кидает исключений, даже если нет достаточно памяти, это решается всякими виртуальными машинами (как например в c#) или подобными трюками, но цена за это - медленнодействие.

Comment: Гарантировано source не равен null. Этот обработчик работает раз 8 с изображением в 50 мб. Каждый раз когда я запускаю обработчик, результирующее изображение добавляется в стек. А исходное то же. При клонировании исходного изображения, приложение занимает еще 140 мб. Таким образом, объем занятой ОП растет. Мне нужно как-то словить исключение, и удалить первое изображение. Если я беру небольшое изображение, где-то с расширением 1024*768, работает без сбоев.

Comment: Ну могу поздравить! В твоем конкретном случае (не универсально) решение есть. конструктор QImage возвращает null если нехватка памяти ("QImage constructors will create a null image if not enough memory exists instead of throwing an exception", но ты можешь кинуть исключение сам). А в общем случае динамическое выделение памяти само по себе не кидает исключений, даже если нет достаточно памяти, это решается всякими виртуальными машинами (как например в c#) или подобными трюками, но цена за это - медленнодействие.